# Thermodynamic relations from Gibbs-Duhem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Given the [Gibbs-Duhem relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Duhem_equation) 
$V dp = N d \mu + S dT$, I am having trouble deriving the following identity:

$\ \left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial \mu}\right)_{V,T} = N \left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial p}\right)_T$

The problem is that the variables $N$ and $\rho$ don't appear as infinitisemals in the equation. How can I proceed?

Comment: Start by noting that the density is inversely proportional to volume:   *ρ* = *m* / *V*, and also that the mass *m* equals the substance's molar mass *M* multiplied by the number of moles *N*:     *m* = *M N*. Together we have,

*ρ* = *M* (*N* / *V*)

(*M* will be carried through the rest of the derivation as an arbitrary constant with dimensions kg / mol.)

Answer (score 1):

$\left( \frac {\partial N} {\partial \mu} \right)_{V,T} = \left( \frac {\partial (\rho V) } {\partial \mu} \right)_{V,T}$
 since $V$ constant, this is the same as:
$\left(V \frac {\partial \rho} {\partial \mu} \right)_{V,T}$.

From there you can put:
$\left(V \frac {\partial \rho} {\partial p} \frac {\partial p} {\partial \mu} \right)_{V,T}$
where $\frac {\partial p} {\partial \mu} = \frac {dp} {d\mu}= \frac {N} {V}$ under $T$ constant, as can be deduced from the Gibbs-Duhem relation. So you get:
$\left( \frac {\partial N} {\partial \mu} \right)_{V,T} = \left(V \frac {\partial \rho} {\partial p} \frac {\partial p} {\partial \mu} \right)_{V,T} = \left(V \frac {\partial \rho} {\partial p} \frac {N} {V} \right)_{V,T} = N \left(\frac {\partial \rho} {\partial p} \right)_{T}$